# np.tensordot for rotation of point clouds?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

Rotation about the origin is a matrix product that can be done with numpy's dot function,

```
import numpy as np
points = np.random.rand(100,3)  # 100 X, Y, Z tuples.  shape = (100,3)
rotation = np.identity(3)  # null rotation for example
out = np.empty(points.shape)
for idx, point in enumerate(points):
    out[idx,:] = np.dot(rotation, point)
```

This involves a for loop, or numpy tile could be used to vectorize.  I think there is an implementation involving np.tensordot, but the function is witchcraft to me.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can just do `out = (rotation @ points[:, :, np.newaxis])[:, :, 0]`. Or `out = np.einsum('ij,nj->ni', rotation, points)`. Or with tensor dot `out = np.tensordot(points, rotation, axes=[1, 1])`.

Comment: Thank you!  Einsum is actually the fastest for 100 points -- 5x faster than tensordot, and 33x faster than the for loop.  With 1000 points tensordot wins -- it seems to have a ~14us dispatch overhead on my machine, but relatively constant time up to large arrays.  I think the matmul solution is the most general, since it is always competitive with the best performance.  Thank you again -- if you submit an answer I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can do that. With [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) you can do:

```
out = np.matmul(rotation, points[:, :, np.newaxis])[:, :, 0]
```

Or, equivalently, if you are using Python 3.5 or later:

```
out = (rotation @ points[:, :, np.newaxis])[:, :, 0]
```

Another way is with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
out = np.einsum('ij,nj->ni', rotation, points)
```

Finally, as you suggested, you can also use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html):

```
out = np.tensordot(points, rotation, axes=[1, 1])
```

Note that in this case `points` is the first argument and `rotation` the second, otherwise the dimensions at the output would be reversed.